# What is the word for an example to illustrate the contrast?

Tags: expressions

> For example, “She has a big blue book” can be said as “She has a big and blue book”, so you cannot use a hyphen between “big” and “blue.” **As a counter example**, "He is a world-famous singer" cannot be said as "He is a world and famous singer", so you should join the words with a hyphen.

I am writing the sentence above, but cannot come up with an appropriate expression to alternatively use in the place of the bold-faced one. I googled the expression **as a counter example**, but I think this expression is maybe so uncommon that little articles used such an expression. Can anyone recommend some expressions that I can use instead of that?

Comment: Come to think of it, simple *Conversely* might work in that place.

Comment: A counterexample is one that argues against a point, so it wouldn't quite work here. If you were to go that route you'd have to say "As an example of the other kind" or something equally verbose.

Answer (score 3):

Use *conversely* as <strike>@Gwangmu Lee</strike> you <strike>suggests</strike> suggested, or the phrase *on the other hand*.

For example, “She has a big blue book” can be said as “She has a big and blue book”, so you cannot use a hyphen between “big” and “blue.” { *Conversely | On the other hand* }, "He is a world-famous singer" cannot be said as "He is a world and famous singer", so you should join the words with a hyphen.

Comment: Note that the commenter you cite is the OP himself :) P.S. Another favourite option of mine is "whereas". And of course simply "but" and "however" usually suit, although they require a little more effort on the reader's part to figure out where the contrast lies...

Comment: @LukeSawczak doesn't the contrast lie in the preceding sentence? If the readers don't understand it, then even *conversely* or *on the other hand* couldn't help.

Comment: @Ooker "Conversely" is a nice, exact word used to show the other side of the coin, an example of a different kind. "But" can mean that, or it could introduce a reason why the former observation is *wrong*. It has more functions, so it requires more careful reading to know which one is intended.